# dict values are stack upon each other

Tags: python, json

Suppose my scene has 2 items, named `arte_item1` and `arte_item2`..
I managed to checked against some attributes in the items which checks against the 'keys' in this json file of mine.
And currently I am having issues, trying to append the data into dictionary

My json file is as follows:

```
{
    "common": {
        "yellow": [
            "SPEC 0.723",
            "RGB 0.002 0.002 0.002",
            "OCC 0.8 1.2"
        ], 
        "blue": [
            "SPEC 0.9",
            "RGB 0.014 0.019 0.047",
            "OCC 0.345"
        ]
    },
    "uncommon":{
        "blue-ish green": [
            "SPEC 0.9",
            "RGB 0.014 0.019 0.047",
            "OCC 0.345"
        ],
        "gray": [
            "SPEC 1",
            "RGB 0.012 0.012 0.012",
            "OCC 0.4"
        ], 
        "black": [
            "SPEC 0.9", 
            "RGB 0.067 0.067 0.067",
            "OCC 0.4" 
        ]
    },
    "rare": {
        "gold": [
            "SPEC 0.723",
            "RGB 0.002 0.002 0.002",
            "OCC 0.3"
        ], 
        "silver": [
            "SPEC 1",
            "RGB 0.349 0.349 0.349",
            "OCC 0.3"
        ]
    }
}
```

While I am expecting my dict output to be something like:

```
 {"arte1" : {u'gold': [u'RGB', u'0.002', u'0.002', u'0.002'], u'silver': [u'RGB', u'0.349', u'0.349', u'0.349']}, 
  "arte2" : {u'blue-ish green': [u'RGB', u'0.014', u'0.019', u'0.047'], u'gray': [u'RGB', u'0.012', u'0.012', u'0.012'], u'black': [u'RGB', u'0.067', u'0.067', u'0.067']}}
```

I am getting the following results, in which the color values are all appended together, like being 'stacked' upon each other..

```
{"arte1" : {u'gold': [u'RGB', u'0.002', u'0.002', u'0.002'], u'silver': [u'RGB', u'0.349', u'0.349', u'0.349'], u'blue-ish green': [u'RGB', u'0.014', u'0.019', u'0.047'], u'gray': [u'RGB', u'0.012', u'0.012', u'0.012'], u'black': [u'RGB', u'0.067', u'0.067', u'0.067']},
 "arte2" : {u'gold': [u'RGB', u'0.002', u'0.002', u'0.002'], u'silver': [u'RGB', u'0.349', u'0.349', u'0.349'], u'blue-ish green': [u'RGB', u'0.014', u'0.019', u'0.047'], u'gray': [u'RGB', u'0.012', u'0.012', u'0.012'], u'black': [u'RGB', u'0.067', u'0.067', u'0.067']}}
```

The following is my code:

```
# arte_item1 -> gives the key 'rare'
# arte_item2 -> gives the key 'uncommon'

def read_json(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)I
        return data

    get_color_info = {}
    get_full_info = {}

    # possibilities comes from read_json(), so in this case, it will be data['rare'] and data['uncommon']
    for index, names in table_data:
        ...
        if not names  is None:
            ...
        for name, color in possibilities.items():
            for item in color:
                if "RGB" in item:
                    get_color_info[name] = item.replace(' ', ',').split(',')
                    get_full_info[item_name] = get_color_info
```

Greatly appreciate if anyone could give me a feed back

Comment: Your data example is not valid JSON data, 'uncommon' is not proper enclosed.

Comment: It looks like you're almost adding references to the same dictionary to your outer dictionary several times. You need to recreate the dictionary instead. I'm not sure I understand your code well enough to fix it (there's a lot of confusing stuff, and it's not runnable), but I'd suggest seeing if you can move the line `get_color_info = {}` inside one of the loops somewhere.

Comment: Agree to @Blckknght said, from you code it looks like you are populate the same dictionary. also look at the wrong result been generated, the two items: 'arte1' and 'arte2', their value are same!

Comment: Thanks guys, I am able to get it over with :)